# Java code using JavaSci API of Scilab doesnt run

Tags: java, scilab

I am using Scilab 6.0.0 and I want to use it through Java code. The Java code I am using is being run through IntelliJ IDEA 1.4. The code is..

```
import org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scilab sci = new Scilab(false);
        sci.open();
        sci.exec("disp(%pi);");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But, it is always giving the following error : 
[image]

I think there is some problem with the environment variables or classpath.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, no proper help, but https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/javasci_step_by_step.html lists two JAR files that have to be on the classpath - did you add them both?

Comment: @Marco13 How to do that in IntelliJ or Eclipse?

Comment: In Eclipse, select Project -> Properties. In the Tree, select "Java Build Path". Select the "Libraries" Tab. Click "Add external JARs". Add both SciLab JARs. (This is only a guess. If it doesn't help, I might try to allocate some time to try it out, but can't promise that something helpful will come out there....)